# JavaScript code can't $get a control in windows7 but can in xp

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging

The following javascript function used to work:

```
  function tbComment_onKeyDown(ID) {
      var commentPop = $find("WebDialogWindowComment")
      commentPop.set_windowState($IG.DialogWindowState.Normal);
      commentID = ID;

      var thePopUpTb = $get("WebDialogWindowComment$tmpl$tbCommentPopUp");
      thePopUpTb.focus();
      thePopUpTb.value = commentID.value;      
}
```

What it did was onKeyDown on a textbox on my aspnet (3.5) form, it caused an infragistics WebDialogWindow to become visible, set the focus to a textbox in that window, and copied over any text from the original texbox to the textbox in the WebDialogWindow.

Now, $get("WebDialogWindowComment$tmpl$tbCommentPopUp"); is returning null. When I look at View Source on the page, WebDialogWindowComment$tmpl$tbCommentPopUp is on the page.

I am running the code thru (the webbrowser in )vs2008 .  The only difference I can think of from when it worked to now, is that I upgraded from vista to windows7. I am not using JQuery.

Also, this code works thru vs2008 on another, xp, machine.

And, the application on the development server (an xp machine) runs on my windows 7 machine.

Can anyone help out with what is going on here?

Comment: ie7 is a browser and xp is an operating system.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected that. Thanks. Seems to have been a browser not os issue anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebDialogWindowComment$tmpl$tbCommentPopUp` looks like an element name. [$get()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397717.aspx) works with element ids, not names. Try:

```
var thePopUpTb = $get("WebDialogWindowComment_tmpl_tbCommentPopUp");
```

Prior to version 8, Internet Explorer mistakenly accepted element names in its [document.getElementById()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28VS.85%29.aspx) method. That's probably why your code works under IE7 on Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks! Wish I had asked you before I spent 2 hours on this. What is weird, the webserver on the xp machine delivers that same code:  var thePopUpTb = $get("WebDialogWindowComment$tmpl$tbCommentPopUp"); and that it works on the machine running ie8.  That is why I thought it was a windows 7 web server issue.

Comment: @Lill, that IE8 browser might be running in IE7 compatibility mode :)

Comment: Actually, just tried it, and the code still works in ie8 even with compatibilty view off.

Comment: @Lill, that's strange... Out of curiosity, can you hit `F12` in IE and confirm that `Browser Mode` is set to `IE8` and `Document Mode` is set to `IE8 Standards`?

Comment: @Frederic. Yup, that is how they are set.